# Ag-grid: How to change define column headerName when using AggFunc?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

For a given column definition, when using aggFunc the headerName appears in format func(string) - I just want the header to display the string I define. This behaviour does not exist when AggFunc is null.

```
const  columnDef: any = {

    headerName: 'Test',
    field: date,
    suppressMenu: true,
    width: 80,
    editable: true,
    lockPosition: true,
    type: 'numericColumn',
    aggFunc: function(data) {

      let sum = 0;
      data.forEach( function(value) {
        if (value) {
            sum = sum + parseFloat(value);
          }
      } );
      if (!sum) { return null; }

      return sum.toFixed(2);
    },
}
```

The headerName should say "test", but will instead show func(test).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHPMh.jpg

Comment: can you create a working example on StackBlitz?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to mark this property as true in your `gridOptions`.

```
suppressAggFuncInHeader : true;
```

As per docs-

> When true, column headers won't include the aggFunc, eg 'sum(Bank
>   Balance)' will just be 'Bank Balance'.

Comment: The docs don't mention this is a grid property, not a column property. So I can't use your solution in the column properties above. Instead...

The actual answer is 

    <ag-grid-angular

    [suppressAggFuncInHeader] = "true"

    ></ag-grid-angular>

Comment: It is not a column property. I have successfully used this in the gridOptions. You can define gridOptions either as an object in component or using the directive in html. Glad it worked for you