# AgGrid: Changing the Aggregation Header Name

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Now I have a column eg name is "age"

```
    {headerName: 'age', field: 'age', filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter', aggFunc: 'sum'}
```

I add a sum aggFunc on it, so the result of header name is changed to "sum(age)"

However, I still want to show "age", how can I implement this?

Thank you very much

Comment: There is an existing answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469594/ag-grid-how-to-change-define-column-headername-when-using-aggfunc

Answer (score 0):

If it is still helpful for someone
when you create gridOptions you need to insert there`suppressAggFuncInHeader: true,`, smth like this:

```
    const gridOptions = {   columnDefs: [
        {
          headerName: 'age',
          field: 'age',
          filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
          aggFunc: 'sum'
        }
], suppressAggFuncInHeader: true, }
```